# Show that $\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1-x^2} = 1$ with the help of the definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The original problem is to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$
I simplified the expression to $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x}{1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}}$
The only definitions and theorems I can use are the definition of a limit and the theorems which states that for two functions $f$ and $g$ that approaches $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively, near $a$ it is true that
(1.) $\lim_{x\to a} f + g = L1 + L2$
(2.) $\lim_{x\to a} fg = L_1L_2$
(3.) $\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{1}{f} = \dfrac{1}{L_1}, \quad $ if $L_1 \neq 0$

In order to use (2.) for the simplified expression I first need to establish that I can use (3.) by showing that $\lim_{x\to 0} 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2} \neq 0, \quad$ so I need to find $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{1-x^2}$ with the help of the definition, since none of the theorems says anything about the composition of functions. I know intuitively that the limit is $1$, so I tried to work out a suitable epsilon-delta proof, but I am stuck, because I feel like requiring $|x| < \delta$ will only make $|1 + \sqrt{1-x^2} - 1| = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ bigger than some $\epsilon$, not smaller.

Comment: @SimpleArt What do you mean? I can't just plug in some number. I need to use the definition or the theorems which I listed in my post because the author has told me of nothing else.

Comment: You need to consider $|1+\sqrt{1-x^2}-\color{red}{2}|$ instead, showing that $2$ is the limit of your expression. Alternatively, consider $|\sqrt{1-x^2}-1|$. You seem to use a mix of these two, which results in your current issues.

Comment: @hampadampadoo At $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{1-x^2}$, just straight plug in $x=0$, no?

Comment: After your reduction, note that $1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 1$, so the absolute value of $f(x)-0$ is $\le |x|$.

Comment: @SimpleArt And how is this using the definition of a limit? How does it prove anything?

Comment: @hampadampadoo You simply said that you needed to solve that limit to use $(3)$, and since that limit does not result in any indefinite forms, converges to a finite value, and is a continuous function, you can just plug $x=0$ in.  Didn't they teach you that you can plug in values for some cases yet?  Its much easier than what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SimpleArt I said that I needed to solve the limit to use (3) and that the only things I know about are the theorems and the definitions I listed in my post. I have no idea what you are talking about, although I appreciate the help.

Comment: @hampadampadoo While you know $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne f(a)$ all of the time, sometimes, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, in particular, if $f$ is defined at $x=a$ as a finite value, and if $f$ is continuous in the region near $x=a$.  Probably more interested in the region $x=a\pm\epsilon$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to see that the solutions of the inequality $|\sqrt{1-x^2}-1|<\varepsilon$ fill a neighborhood of $0$.

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
1-\varepsilon<\sqrt{1-x^2}<1+\varepsilon
$$
and the part $\sqrt{1-x^2}<1+\varepsilon$ holds for every $x$ in the domain of the function. So we need to compute the solutions for
$$
1-\varepsilon<\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
It is not restrictive to assume $0<\varepsilon\le 1$, so the inequality becomes
$$
1-2\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2<1-x^2
$$
that's satisfied for
$$
x^2<\varepsilon(2-\varepsilon)
$$
so for
$$
|x|<\sqrt{\varepsilon(2-\varepsilon)}=\delta
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be our function. We want to show that for any given $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a $\delta$ such that if $0\lt |x-0|\lt\delta$, then $|f(x)-0|\lt \epsilon$.

Note that $1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 1$, at least when $|x|\le 1$. (When $|x|\gt 1$, it is not defined.) It follows that for such $x$ we have
$$\left|\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|\le |x|.$$

Let $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon)$. If $0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta$, then $|f(x)-0|\lt \epsilon$.